# pause threading.Timer for 1hr

Tags: python, multithreading

What I am doing is checking for new content on a website. The threading.Timer checks every 50 seconds for new content. If found new content i want it to pause the function for 1hr.

```
def examplebdc ():
threading.Timer(50.00, examplebdc).start ();
#content id
wordv = 'asdfsdfm'

if any("m" in s for s in wordv):
    print("new post")
    #pause this threading.Timer (or function) for 1hr. 
examplebdc();
```

Comment: [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)?

Comment: @NPE i tried that. it doesn't stop or pause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to not restart the timer until you know how long you want to wait before calling your function again:

```
def examplebdc():
    wordv = 'asdfsdfm'

    if any("m" in s for s in wordv):
        print("new post")
        threading.Timer(60*60, examplebdc).start()
    else:
        threading.Timer(50, examplebdc).start()

examplebdc()
```

If that's not possible for some reason, you can change how you create and start your timer so that you can reference it later and cancel it:

```
def examplebdc():
    # lets assume we need to set up the 50 second timer immediately
    timer = threading.Timer(50, examplebdc)   # save a reference to the Timer object
    timer.start()                             # start it with a separate statement

    wordv = 'asdfsdfm'

    if any("m" in s for s in wordv):
        print("new post")
        timer.cancel()                        # cancel the previous timer
        threading.Timer(60*60, examplebdc).start()   # maybe save this timer too?

examplebdc()
```

In your single function this is easy, you can just use a variable. If your timer was being started somewhere else, you might need to use one or more `global` statements or some other more complex logic to pass the Timer reference around.